# MMC error in Windows Server 2003 R2 SP2

Tags: mmc, windows-server-2003

I'm getting following error while accessing "Disk Management" in "Management Console":

> MMC has detected an error in a snap-in. It is recommended that you
>   shut down and restart MMC.

OS Windows Server 2003 R2 SP2.

Comment: MMC VERSION 3.0

Comment: Your title says R3, question body R2. Please [edit] to correct and please avoid all-caps in the future.